Piezo tr switch no echo signal
I set this circuit to use piezo as transceiver. I can perfectly transfer the transmitter signal (10 burst pulse) but as transmitter still connected onto piezo , any reveived signal is disappears. When I disconnect the transmitter output and test it by transmitting from another piezo there is no problem with receiving. How can I modify my circuit to receive echo signals ?
THE Y1-CRYSTAL is the piezo in circuit.
I do not add any links because it is my design.

I changed my circuit to this one below.
I tried both fet and bjt built and nmos.

BJT built output below , natural response is huge and takes time to fade away.

Circuits below has nmos on cascode.
Here is output with piezo not loaded VDD 9v

Here is output with piezo  loaded VDD 9v

Here is output with piezo not loaded VDD 16v

Here is output with piezo loaded VDD 16v


A single piezo serving both transmit and receive requires a long time for built-up 40 kHz energy in the piezo to dissipate after a transmit burst. Only after this ring-down period do reflected pulses exceed ring-down amplitude. This means that objects close to the transducer are not detectable. Just how close do you expect objects to be detected?

you still are loading your crytal with your R1 when Q1 is off. So, you don't have a "TXENABLED" circuit, you have a "DISCONNECT RX" circuit so far. (And why you would use an opamp to drive TXENABLED is beyond me, this is clearly a job for a single transistor or a pair, and it's especially not a job for the LM741, which is not rail-to-rail, and likely to latch up. Come on, you already demonstratably know how to switch a voltage with a transistor, and you're in your third EE year, you can do better!)
Solution would simply to replace R1 with another MOSFET and make this a Push/Pull output stage that you can put to a high-output-impedance mode by putting both MOSFETs into disabled mode.
Note that these are pretty many discrete diodes that do half the job you need for the fact that you could have used a cheap analog switch IC with a supply voltage in the same range as your TXENABLED voltage, so, probably 10V ?
Examples would include the very old and available HEF4053 / 74HC4053 / CD4053 / TMUX4053 / NLV14053.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
